# Failed npm install command weinre in windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm, weinre

I have tried to install weinre for debug a phonegap application with command:
    npm install weinre

I have always the same error:

[image: npm command]

I use windows 7, I opened the cmd with administrator, i have installed node.js. I have read other questions about this but i don't have a solution.

Please, could you help me?

Comment: "you or one of your dependencies are requesting a package version that doesn't exist". that has nothing to do with win7/admin rights...

Comment: You didn't specify a version, and there are no versions released that match `*`, so an error is thrown. Specify which version you wish to install.

Comment: Do You know if i need to put something else in the command to install? or where do i should see this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I put this: npm install weinre@latest and works :)

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for the coments. The problem is because I didnt put a version of weinre. I use the command `npm install weinre@latest` and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the latest Weinre version number. Also it's probably advisable to do a global install, so you'd use:

```
npm -g install weinre@2.0.0-pre-I0Z7U9OV
```